# javascript regex pattern for _water_glass

Tags: javascript, regex, lodash, tv4

I need a javascript regex pattern to test a schema variable, so that it should have either of the following.

1. It can start with any character followed by "_water_glass" and must not be anything after water_glass like "xxxx_water_glass"

or

2. It can be just "water_glass" not necessary to have character before water_glass and must not be anything after water_glass.

Could anyone help on this please to get the regex pattern.

Comment: "country_code" can mean a lot of things. Are you talking about [ISO 3166-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1) codes? If so, the 2 digit ones? The 3 digit ones? Why are you using regex and not just a list? **Have you tried anything yourself or are you expecting others to do your work for free?** If so you may [want to hire a freelancer](http://www.freelancer.com).

Comment: I mean exact word "country_code" and not 3 or 2 digit code. since its confusing i replaced it like "water_glass" now.

Comment: So is your actual question "how to match a word ending with a specific pattern?" Look up the `$` anchor in regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simply `/^.*_?\_water_glass/`

```
    var re = /^.*_?_water_glass/mg; 
var str = 'horse.mp3_country_code\n4343434_country_code\n_country_code';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```

DEMO https://regex101.com/r/gB9zL7/2

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

`^(?:.+_|)water_glass$`

**Details**:

- `^`- start of string
- `(?:.+_|)` - an optional 1+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, up to the last `_` including it
- `water_glass` - a `water_glass` substring
- `$`  - end of string.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oU7xY9/2) and a demo code below:

```
var re = /^(?:.+_|)water_glass$/gm; 
var str = 'xxxx_water_glass\nwater_glass';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```